# A  Simple Regression Model for Our Experiment?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, estimation, descriptive-statistics, computational-statistics

We know, In statistics, simple linear regression is the least squares estimator of a linear regression model with a single explanatory variable. In other words, simple linear regression fits a straight line through the set of n points in such a way that makes the sum of squared residuals of the model (that is, vertical distances between the points of the data set and the fitted line) as small as possible.

suppose in simple linear regression model

> $y= \alpha + \beta x + \epsilon $

, from a random instance we gather this information:

> $ \bar{x}=\bar{y}, \Sigma x_iy_i = \Sigma x_{i}^{2} $

I want to calculate estimation $(\alpha, \beta)$ with least square method. how I can solve it?

> Infact I'm a Biology Background, and for experiment need this value.
>   thanks.

Comment: There is no reason in general why $\sum x_i y_i = \sum x_i^2$: in fact that minimally requires the same units of measurement. You mean something else, I imagine, but it is not clear what.

Comment: @NickCox, we gather this from our information.

Comment: Your question sounds increasingly like a self-study question and should be flagged as such.

Comment: @NickCox, what do you mean by "self-study"?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Note that @statchrist made the same comment in their answer.

Comment: this is a research question. i read it. thanks @NickCox.

Comment: If it's a research question, how do you know that the equalities mentioned hold? Note that there is the same question about equality of the means. If you have data, why not just use them? If this is about a matter of principle, why suppose they hold? The equalities do not even make sense unless $y$ and $x$ are measured in the same units.

Comment: While voting was under way to close this as self-study without an attempt at an answer from the OP, Mina declared that it is not self-study. If so, then I think the criterion for closing is now that the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to be a self-study question.

One way to solve the problem ist to look at the mathematical expression for the estimator in matrix notation:

$\hat{\beta}_{OLS}=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$.

Insert the matrices for your model in matrix notation: $y = X\beta_{OLS} + \epsilon$.

For instance with $\beta_{OLS} = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ \beta \end{pmatrix}$ and $X=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & X_1 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & X_n \end{pmatrix}$. Next step would be to manipulate this equation in order to get expressions in terms of the mean and insert the additional information you have.

Comment: i couldent get it, you means final value is (0,1) ?, is it possible learn me ?

Comment: oooh, i got it thanks. but last step is how we can get numerical value for our experiment ?

Comment: it dosent satisfy me, is it possible to make it clear?‌it's (0,1) ?

Comment: Yes, have you tried and computed the inverse of X'X/N?

Comment: Is it possible to add it to your answer, no, this is difficult for me. if i didnt waste your time, please add...

Comment: is it possible to complete your answer?

Comment: please learn me how calculate it ?

Comment: i think i waste your time, is it ?

Comment: is is possible complete it?